# Multiple testing corrections and descriptive statistics

Tags: confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons, descriptive-statistics

Let's say a have a medical study and I need to describe a structure of a sample: 20% patients died, 10% of patients were cured and so on. 
I'm gonna count a confidence interval for each of these proportions. 
Do I have to consider the fact that there are more than one CI? Do I have to do a multiple testing correction? 
Or can I just count 95% CI for each proportion?

Comment: Confidence intervals are not descriptive statistics.

Comment: @MichaelChernick So, I shouldn't use them in this case?

Comment: Boxplots, histograms, pie charts, bar charts are descriptive.  Confidence intervals are inferential and therefore not descriptive.  You are right that multiplicity doesn't enter when dealing with descriptive things.  If you want to construct confidence intervals which corresponds to a hypothesis tests you need to take multiplicity into account. If you want to stay descriptive use a bar chart or pie chart for the summary.

Comment: This may still be considered controversial as many people do not accept multiplicity corrections.  I saw this in the medical field but rarely among statisticians.

Comment: @MichaelChernick What if I want to estimate the population parameters using my sample? Can I use CI for this? And what if I estimate two or more parameters?

Comment: When you are only doing a small number of tests (say 2) the penalty for adjustment may not be so great that it wouldn't hurt much to ignore the multiplicity.  I really hate saying what I just said. There are ways like using the bootstrap for p-value adjustment that are not as conservative as Bonferroni.  When the number of tests get very large as is the case in genetics less stringent criteria like family wise error rate can be replaced by with false discovery rate. I have been part of several discussions on these topics on this site recently.  Searching the site might be illuminating.